# Client systems periodically have issues resolving DNS

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

We have a remote office who connects to a DNS server (running on Windows Server 2008 R2) located at a different office which it connects to via WAN. Periodically, when clients in this office are trying to resolve system names within our corporate network they will be unable to.

If you unplug the ethernet cable from their laptop for even just half a second and plug it back in, DNS resolution comes right back up.

This is an odd issue that I haven't encountered before. Does anybody have any idea where I may need to begin looking?

Long term I'd like to get a local DNS server in that remote office but I don't currently have a budget to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just DNS resolution fails?  Not pinging an IP?  If you don't disconnect the cable does it come back on its own after a minute or two?

Comment: I just checked both of these. It can still ping devices by IP, only DNS resolution does not work (it can even ping the DNS servers by IP so they are still connected in that sense). If you don't disconnect the cable it will not come back.

Comment: Do an ipconfig /all on one of them when it fails.  I wonder if there's 3rd party software changing the DNS server to something else on the clients when this occurs and then unplugging and plugging it back in gets DHCP to update it again.

Comment: I have a client system with the issue right now so I'm able to troubleshoot. Nothing has changed the DNS servers so it isn't that. The primary DNS server is set to the DNS server at the site across the WAN (which it can ping) and the secondary is a Google DNS server (8.8.8.8). Can this cause any issues?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the DNS client service on the client PC? What is the average ping time to the DNS Server and are you suffering from any packet loss when pinging with '-t' ?

Comment: In period of DNS outage, what is `NSLOOKUP any_DNSname_in_main_office DNS_server_ip` command output? <br> Do this issue cover all DNS records from your DNS server or only some of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: don't mix internal and external nameservers.

Long answer:
Are these machines joined to a domain? Or if not, is your DNS server resolving internal names? Either way, it sounds like your client DNS settings are at fault. If you have more than one nameserver configured and the first one becomes unreachable but the second is, Winows will "latch" onto the second one until it becomes unreachable. I suggest you forego the external resolver and stick with just the one, or bite the bullet and stand up an additional nameserver. If you /really/ need the external resolver, you may look into Name Resolution Policies which allow for per domain name DNS server settings. While primarily intended for VPNs or similar functions, they may be of use here. See more here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff394369.aspx.